# Query Shipping charge magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, soap-api-v2, android

I want to write custom api for getting shipping charge from magento DB. How to query shipping charge from magento DB in php.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a method for this, which also returns the price.

Method:

- cart_shipping.list (SOAP V1)
- shoppingCartShippingList (SOAP V2)

Link: https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartShipping/cart_shipping.list.html

Comment: Thanks Anna Völkl for your reply. But in the back end magento guys are using some plugin for shipping charge. Depending on distance they are setting the shipping charge. They made some changes in the backend, now we are getting that shipping charge from that plugin.

Comment: If you want an answer to this, you should create a new question with all the details and code. Otherwise no one will be able to answer this.

Comment: If you know pls help -> How can i apply extra shipping charge for only selected products sku? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/238570/57334

Comment: mam is there a way to configure shipping charges based on the category?am having a hard time dealing with this