# How Can I Add Packing Charge for Only Selected Products Using Shopping Cart Price Rule?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, extrafee

I need to apply Package charges for sensitive products!

how can I add Packing charge for only selected products SKU's using **shopping cart Pricing Rule**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"Custom Options"**.

You can add custom option from Magento admin for a particular product.

Also I suggest this extension: https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-surcharge.html